# MiKTeX-Repo offline - how to build a custom repo?

Tags: windows, latex, repository, miktex

I tried to download some additional packages for miktex, but it seems that the website has problems (it's running IIS...).
The miktex package manager can't connect to online-repo. I tried to reach the [miktex-repo](http://miktex.org/pkg/repositories) through my browser, but it gives back a server-error.

I found another ftp-based repository [here (ftp)](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/) ([http-link](http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/)).
I downloaded the needed package, and tried to tell miktex-package-manager that my download-dir is my repo, but something's missing.

My research showed how-to's for linux only, so I hope somebody can tell me how to create a local repository for miktex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution (the miktex-website is now completly offline):

I opened that ftp-repository mentioned above with filezilla and downloaded everything (be patient, that's 1,07 GB).
After everything was downloaded, MiKTeX Package Manager accepted the target-directory as local Repository.

Comment: The repository may also be cloned via `wget -r --no-parent ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/`.